# My tooltip is cut off by the limits of a div element

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I need to make appear a tooltip when a message box is "hovered". All message boxes are inside a div called chatbox.
My problem is that the tooltip is cut off by the chatbox div when pass the limits of the chatbox. 
Here is a `jsfiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/Ifalcao/k9Yrc/2.

The overflow rule in the chatbox div must exist, otherwise if I have many message boxes, they will pass the limit of the chatbox (http://jsfiddle.net/Ifalcao/URBDE).

I need the message boxes inside the chatbox but the tooltips of the message boxes outside the chatbox.

Help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to work in your fiddle - I made the tooltip a child of 'body', and positioned it next to the box -here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k9Yrc/8/

```
$('.box').hover(function(){
                var boxLeft = $(this).offset().left;
                var boxTop = $(this).offset().top;
                var htmltooltip = '<div id="info" class="shadow">';
                htmltooltip += '<h4>Label info</h4>';
                htmltooltip += '<img src="images/defaultphoto.gif"/>';
                htmltooltip += '</div>';
                $('body').append(htmltooltip).children('#info').hide().fadeIn(400).css('left', boxLeft - 150).css('top', boxTop + 100);
                }, function() {
                    $('#info').remove();
                    }
            );
```